# Override Equals for Hashmap<String,String>

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I have Hashmap,how to override equals method for the hashmap?

Thanks.

Comment: HashMap already has an `equals()` method. It's not your responsibility to write `equals()` methods for classes you didn't create.

Comment: And why would You want to do it ? If you really have to, you need to extend it and override equals - but WHY ?

Comment: You can override a class' method while subclassing it. But why do you want to change the equals behavior of HashMap?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose i need to check the following
1) whether all the key present in 1st map is also there in 2nd map
2) if 1st is satisfied i also need to check if they key have the same value in both the maps.
Note: here hashmap<string,string>

Comment: @Pradheep: that would violate the equals() contract, and is thus not the job of an equals() method: [a=b] can't be equal to [a=b, c=d], even if that matches your definition of "equal". The default equals method returns trus if both map have equal keys associated with equal values.

Comment: @JBNizet so you are saying that for my requirement the default equals for hashmap is enough?

Comment: If what you actually want is to check if two maps have the same keys, associated with the same values, then yes. But what you said initially was that you wanted to check if all keys in map1 were also in map2, with the same values. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @JBNizet i checked what u said,hashmap's default equals also checks  if all keys in map1 were also in map2

Comment: @Pradheep: **and vice-versa**. That's the key part. If map2 has all the keys of map1, **but also other keys**, then they're not equal. To be equal, the maps must have the same keys, because if map1.equals(map2) is true, then map2.equals(map1) must also be true.

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can do:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(){
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO comparison here
        return super.equals(o);
    }
};
map.equals(new HashMap<String, String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

In HashMap already equals() method is overrriden.If you want to override object class equals()
method eclipse shortcut key--->alt+shift+s+v

Select the equals method click on ok.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a class of your own which extends Hashmap

```
public class NewHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K, V>
```

and override the equals method in that

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Your code
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, make a separate method somewhere to compare the specific hashmaps you want. For example:

```
public class HashMapComparator {
    boolean static areMapsEqual(HashMap<String, String> aMap, HashMap<String, String> bMap) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
boolean mapsAreEqual = HashMapComparator.areMapsEqual(firstMap, secondMap);
```

Although you should know that this is an incorrect solution in case you want to use your `equals` method when searching or sorting lists of these HashMaps. I'm assuming that is not the case.