# Should I override equals() and hashCode() for String key in HashMap, Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, equals, hashcode

I'm using `HashMap<String, MySuperClass>` collection, where the key is in `String` format. In general, in order to use `HashMap` collection, it's necessary to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

I want to clarify, should I override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `String`, `Integer`, and other «primitive» classes in `HashMap`?

Comment: Huh? `String` and `Integer` are built-in classes that already have `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Yeap, that's the reason for the question. In some places I read that in case of `String` and `Integer` it's not necessary but in other places people implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for these classes as well. So, I want to clarify this moment.

Comment: "in other places people implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for these classes" Where?

Comment: @AndyTurner, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22904620/462347

Comment: @MikeB. that code overrides the map's equals method, not String's equals method...

Comment: @assylias, oops, right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. `String`s (and `Integer`s) already implement `equals` and `hashCode`, and there's no way you can override it for them since those classes are `final`, hence not extensible.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a class as a key for a `HashMap` (or `HashSet`, or `Hashtable` for that matter), you should make sure it overrides `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)`. The JDK's `String`, the primitive wrappers (such as `Integer`, `Long`, etc.) and many others already do this for you, so you don't need to worry about it.